# How to implement code checking into my submit form

Tags: php, html, verification

i have the following form

```
    <form action="/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/welcome.php" method="post" class="basic-grey">
<h1>Form
<span>Please fill all the texts in the fields.</span>
</h1>
<label>
<span>Your Nickname* :</span>
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="It will appear in the text" />
</label>

<label>
<span>Your Email* :</span>
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Valid Email Address" />
</label>

<label>
<span>Message* :</span>
<textarea id="messagebook" name="messagebook" placeholder="The text that will appear" maxlength="80"></textarea>
</label>
<label>
<span>Code* :</span>
<input id="code" type="text" name="code" placeholder="The Code That we sent to your email" maxlength="8" />
</label>
<label>
<span> </span>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Send" />
</label>
</form>
```

which uses the following php, this php basically posts the message value into a txt file

```
<?php
$var = $_POST['messagebook'];
file_put_contents("/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
exit();
?>
```

but i want the submit button only work if my code field matches with the codes that are stored in a txt file like this

```
zACHAS5r
rKUzob3X
omqYjVQZ
BeF375BG
rFKQomMX
y8EVBTGH
Z7icxNoD
wnZ5qBvK
ftbPiCZa
sXJKDETK
wYDVLDPd
AjURjBdZ
LZR4fbtk
gmFY89TV
BAWDxpZ2
bGLLd9Az
qg4C93wN
YJnrDh2c
jwH6hV9h
tm3S4f5j
MU2ikfbu
ZXnUpfmY
hijZPTk4
C2oWha3T
irTg9oUA
jmjLDvL3
jUbiBtJo
gCCAQx6Z
```

Theorically i could make it work with this code, but i dont know where to implement it

```
    function is_valid($code)
{
return in_array($code , explode(' ',file_get_contents('coderoute')));
}
```

EDIT1: Currrently i have this, and i get this error

```
 <?php
    function is_valid($code)
    {
    return in_array($code , explode(' ',file_get_contents("/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/codes.txt")));
    } 
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    if (is_valid($code)) { 
        $var = $_POST['messagebook'];
        file_put_contents("/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
    exit();
?>
```

> PHP Warning: 
>   file_get_contents(/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/codes.txt): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/welcome.php on line 4,

Comment: `if (is_valid) { add_to_file }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
$message_book = $_POST['messagebook'];

if(is_valid($code)) {
    file_put_contents('/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/data.txt', "{$message_book}\n", FILE_APPEND);
    exit();
}

function is_valid($code) {
    $codes = file('/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/codes.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    return in_array($code, $codes);
}
```

You've mentioned `PHP Warning` of `No such file exists`. You could provide absolute path of `codes.txt` to check if it works right.

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: message_book in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/welcome.php on line 6,

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. I've modified the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Code you need to check is in `$_POST['code']`.

So pass it as argument to `is_valid` function:

```
<?php
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    if (is_valid($code)) { 
        $var = $_POST['messagebook'];
        file_put_contents("/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/data.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: now i get this error, however the directory is correct and ive checked the permissions [Thu Dec 15 22:27:01.063358 2016] [:error] [pid 7210] [client 92.59.55.17:60354] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/codes.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wallstreet/welcome.php on line 4

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScript array with the codes, **this array will be filled with PHP**, if the entered code is not in the array, the submit button will not submit the form.

Copy-paste next code in a PHP file and open it in your browser :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function check_code () // ◄■ FUNCTION CALLED FROM THE FORM.
{ var arr = [ <?php // ▼ FILL JAVASCRIPT ARRAY WITH CODES FROM FILE ▼
              $arr = explode( PHP_EOL,file_get_contents('coderoute.txt') );
              echo "'" . implode( "','",$arr ) . "'";
              ?> ];
  var code = document.getElementById("code"); // ◄■ FIELD IN FORM.
  if ( arr.indexOf( code.value ) == -1 ) // ◄■ SEARCH CODE IN ARRAY.
       { alert("Code not found.");
         return false; // ◄■ FORM WILL NOT BE SUBMITTED.
       }
  return true; // ◄■ FORM WILL BE SUBMITTED.
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="somescript.php" onsubmit="return check_code()"> <!-- ◄■ JS FUNCTION -->
      <input type="text" id="code" name="code"/> <!-- ◄■ CODE FIELD -->
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice how the JavaScript array is filled with PHP, the PHP script reads the codes from the file and echo them as the array items of the JavaScript array. **Right click the page** to see the source code and watch how the JavaScript array was filled.